# Nuxt3 updates layouts on every page navigaton

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt3

I have two pages named page1 and page2, And these two pages are wrapped by a layout that contains a menu.

The problem is when I navigate from page 1 to page 2, The layout re-renders (updates) again and every code on the layout executes again that I don't want(on every navigation prints logs).

How can I fix that?

page 1

```
<script setup>

</script>

<template>
  <NuxtLayout name="test">
    <div>
      <h4>page 1</h4>
      <NuxtLink to="/page2">page 2</NuxtLink>
    </div>
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>
```

page 2

```
<script setup>

</script>

<template>
  <NuxtLayout name="test">
    <div>
      <h4>page 2</h4>
      <NuxtLink to="/page1">page 1</NuxtLink>
    </div>
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>
```

test layout

```
<script setup>

onMounted(()=>{
  console.log('mount')
})


console.log('re-render')

</script>

<template>
    <div>
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Looks like you are navigating by <a href="">link</a> or something like that instead of nuxt navigation ":to" etc.

Comment: no i use <NuxtLink to=""></NuxtLink> for navigation @digitalniweb

Comment: I don't think anyone can help you then without providing code or reproducible example. Are you using web developer tools? There might be a hint...

Comment: I provided example @digitalniweb

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code here, Nuxt is doing what you're asking it to AFAIK. Use a `nuxt-page` component as shown in the documentation: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/layouts#enable-layouts Here's you're using the layout as a regular component, hence it's calling the onMounted hook as expected. You do not need to add a layout to the pages themselves because they are already wrapped by it on an upper level.